# Is the following the general foruma for the intrinsic derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

In my textbook I have the following formula for the intrinsic derivative:
$$\frac{\delta T^i}{\delta t} = \frac{d T^i}{dt} + V^m \Gamma^i_{mk}T^k$$
Where $V^m = \frac{dZ^m}{dt}$ are the components of covariant basis vector $\pmb{Z}_m$

What I want to know is the general formula for any number and rank of tensors, I worked out the following for 2 rank 1 tensors:
$$\frac{\delta T^iS_j}{\delta t} = \frac{d T^iS_j}{dt} + V^m (\Gamma^i_{mk}T^kS_j - \Gamma^k_{mj}T^iS_k)$$

Is it correct and can I use these rules for any number of and rank of tensors just like the covariant derivative ?